# How configure Workstation to run on a notebook with 3840x2160 resolution?

Tags: resolution, vmware-workstation

I am trying to get Workstation running on a Dell 9550 that has a very high native resolution of 3840x2160. Workstation runs with no apparent problems. However, when I transfer over a VM that has been running full screen on a desktop host with 1920x1080 resolution it comes up on the notebook with very small icons and text that literally requires a mag glass to read.

I have tried changing the host notebook's resolution to 1920x1080 but I cannot find any set of Workstation VM settings that effectively get me back to a usable resolution like 1920x1080. I have tried every combination of these factors in every order I can think of but the VM insists on coming up at the host's native resolution of 3840x2160 (even after I have dropped the host's resolution down to 1920x1080).

When I right click on the VM's Desktop to try to reduce the VM's resolution the mouse clicks don't seem to be where they visually appear to be and I can't find a way to change the VM's resolution.

Can someone explain what I need to do to get Workstation usable on this notebook?

Comment: What version of Workstation are you using? Have you tried remotely logging off the guest machine to force a resolution change? Is there no options for scaling?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/898712/increase-resolution-to-4k-in-vmware-or-virtualbox

Comment: Thanks Burgi.  Looks like v12 is required (i was using 11).

Comment: Not a problem, don't forget to post that as an answer!